# html5: link to the #id of a div at a certain point on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a responsive header that I'm working on for a site that turns into a fixed-position navbar as you scroll down. It takes up roughly the upper quarter of the page.

The content of the page is in a series of `divs` / cards that slide up as you scroll down.

I want to add `<a href>` links to the navbar that correspond to the `id`s of the `div`s. However, when I do so, the div content moves to the top of the page.

So I get something like the following when I navegate to `/localhost#first_card`

```
---- TOP OF PAGE
[<div id="first_card"> begins here]


---- bottom border of navbar
[<div id="first_card"> continues here]
```

when what I really want is this:

```
---- TOP OF PAGE



---- bottom border of navbar
[<div id="first_card"> begins here]
```

Is there a way to control where on the page the hash link might render the `<div id="first_card">` after navigating to `/localhost#first_card`?

Comment: @FelixKling oh i misunderstood the question sorry .

Comment: can you set up a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to solve this for you in JSFiddle for a bit now, and from what I can find, the best way would be to box all the cards into a seperate element with `overflow:auto`

The result of this, and as proof of it working can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Entoarox/TT2JN/

This may not work for your site, but the only alternative is using javascript to solve this and I cant recommend that because it would cause a massive load on the visitors PC due to most hash related javascript functionality being either static or very new, meaning that to support older browsers, you'd need to manually poll if the hash has changed, either taking up a lot of CPU time, or having a very slow response to when the hash has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery scrollTop() command. This will give you the precise positioning that you need.
http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

You might have to change your links up a little. Example with jQuery and a wrapper div:

```
<a id="first-card-jump" href="#first_card">Jump to First Card</a>

<div id="wrapper">
    NAVBAR
    first div
    second div
    ...
    nth div
</div>

<script>
    $('a#first-card-jump).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Not sure if this is needed
        $('div#wrapper).scrollTop(500); // you have to measure how far down you want to scroll
    });
</script>
```

Note that this might mess up your in-page back button support. Not sure if that's an issue for you.

p.s. If you're in time trouble, the simplest fix is to add a top margin to each div equal to the height of the fixed navbar.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I made you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd3AU/1/)
it uses padding-top to create the offset to the top, then it uses margin-bottom to remove the offset between the elements.

the relevant css:

```
/*
add top padding and substract the same amount from bottom margin
*/

.card {
    padding-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    position: relative;
}

/*
we need to reverse the stacking for this solution, so the elements later in
the document don't cover the elements before

either you know how many cards you have, so you can solve this in a central
css file (like below)
or you must add the stacking upon creation (in your template)
or use the javascript


starts from 2 because nav is :nth-child(1) in this example
*/
.card:nth-child(2){
    z-index: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3){
    z-index: -1;
}
.card:nth-child(4){
    z-index: -2;
}
```

javascript to reverse the stacking, using jQuery

```
$(function(){ //on load
    $('body>.card').each(function(i, elem){$(elem).css('z-index', -i)})
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make a div appear in the middle of the page, right? So, to do this, you can just direct the page to the div above it. You can also make another div above it with a fixed height.

Comment: *you can just direct the page to the div above it* How?